# Connect to MySQL running on raspberry pi in my own laptop

Tags: python, mysql, raspbian

I have been having problems connecting to the database. I have tested the username and password. It works fine and can login to the database. The database has been running.

This is the code for python in my own laptop not the virtual machine.

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='myname', password='mypw', host='169.254.X.X', database='GarageParking') 
    print('success')
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print("Database not successful")
```

The host is the ip addr of the raspberrypi. I had edited the mysql config file to 0.0.0.0. I just have problems connecting to the database only not the login.

The error is 
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '169.254.X.X:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)

phpMyadmin
[image]
I appreciate your help.

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, it keeps hitting the exception which is database not successful. I have no idea, does the fault lies with the input for the host?

Comment: Don't know. If instead of catching the error and printing s vague message you displayed the actual exception, we might be able to work it out.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, printed out the error.
2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '169.254.X.X:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it). I had commented out the bind-addr. But is still not working

Comment: @DanielRoseman, oh is working. I might have accidentally added in smth in the config file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved alr. For those who wants to access the mysql running on raspberry pi,

```
import mysql.connector

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='x', password='x', host='169.254.X.X', database='xx', 
    port=3306) // The host is the ip addr of the raspberry pi which also runs mysql.
    print('success')
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print(e)
```

Remember to comment out the bind-addr in the my.cnf.

The command is

```
 sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Please check if there are anything u have added accidentally in the my.cnf file and remove them appropriately.

After you have modified, restart your server

```
 sudo service mysql restart
```

Please create a user which can be from any host. In this case, it is a #. Please specify choose any host in the phpmyadmin web.